# R: Building function to calculate % relative frequency and apply them over all columns

Tags: r

I am a complete beginner in R and having some problems with building functions...

[image]

My data looks like this.

I would like to build a function so that I can convert all values in the table into % relative frequency per column.

For example, for first column, I would like divide all the values in that column by columnn sum (colSum) of that column.

Then, I would like to repeat that over all columns.

Is there any functions I can look into?
I tried apply function, but I couldn't get it to work.

Thank you:)

Comment: suppose matrix is `m`: `t(t(m) / colSums(m))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `apply` function, you can do:

```r
apply(df,2, function(x) x/sum(x)*100)
```

Here, I created this dummy example to illustrate how it works:

```r
 df <- data.frame(C1 = sample(1:100,5),
                   C2 = sample(1:100,5),
                   C3 = sample(1:100,5))

apply(df,2, function(x) x/sum(x)*100)

            C1        C2       C3
[1,] 32.903226 13.861386 19.59799
[2,] 27.096774  1.980198 16.33166
[3,]  3.870968 44.554455 17.58794
[4,] 15.483871 17.821782 21.85930
[5,] 20.645161 21.782178 24.62312
```

---

Using `dplyr` package, you can get the same output by using `mutate_all`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(.funs = ~./sum(.)*100)

         C1        C2       C3
1 32.903226 13.861386 19.59799
2 27.096774  1.980198 16.33166
3  3.870968 44.554455 17.58794
4 15.483871 17.821782 21.85930
5 20.645161 21.782178 24.62312
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Worked perfectly :)) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Another `base R` option could be:

```
sweep(df, 2, FUN = `/`, colSums(df))*100
```

Comment: Nice ! I did not know `sweep` function ;)

Comment: @dc37 I think that `sweep()` is one of the most underrated `base` functions. It offers quite a lot :)

Comment: I can see that. I'm curious about the pro / cons of `sweep` over `apply` functions. I will have to learn more about it.

Comment: @dc37 in this case it is not obviously better, but in situations when you have a pre-defined vector which you want to apply on specific columns/rows, it is really great.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ;). I will add it to my toolbox

Answer (score 2):

We can replicate the `colSums` to keep the lengths same before doing the division in `base R`

```
df/colSums(df)[col(df)] * 100
```